# DVD-RW doesn't read or write, SAMSUNG NP700Z5C-S03SA notebook

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers

I upgraded my windows from Win 8 to Win 8.1 and I had never used DVD driver, Now when i insert CD or DVD it took some second and then it push it out, but if the DVD was free to write on it just keep inside and ask me if i want to open it or write on it.

I have tried some videos but still doesn't work, i deleted the driver but it keeps coming back, i went to the registry to make some edits but still not work.

my driver details:

Drive: TSSTcorpCDDVDW SU-B08AB SC01

Model Name: TSSTcorpCDDVDW SU-B08AB

Version: SC01

OEM Code: SC

SAMSUNG NP700Z5C-S03SA notebook

Comment: I've got the same TSSTcorp drive, in Windows 10, in a similar Samsung (NP700Z5C-S02UB), and I'm seeing as similar failure. The drive can read CDs and CD-Rs, but can't (successfully) read or write CD-RWs, can't read DVDs (it pops them back out), and can't read or write DVD-Rs or DVR+RWs. I haven't found a solution anywhere. It could just be hardware failure of one of the optical components in the drive. Did you ever find a solution or replace the drive?